# How to create a nested for loop for a list of collections and functions

Tags: java, anylogic

**I want to create a nested for loop that can do the following:**

```
for (Collection c : collection_of_all_collections){
    for (Wait w : collection_of_all_waits){
        function(c, w);
    }
}
```

- The c collections' includes items of type `Int`
- The w collections' includes items of type function `Wait`

//note: these waits are not at main so, I list them by location as `location.wait_ID`.

**The function will do the following:**

//1- access each agent in the wait entities to check a parameter value

//2- if the parameter value is true then add the agent index to the collection c

```
for (Agent me1 : w.waitingEntities )
    if (households(me1.getIndex()).p_HH_willing_to_change == true){
         collection0.add(households(me1.getIndex()).getIndex());
    }else{}
```

//3- for each item in collection c free that agent from the wait w

```
for (int i : c){
    w.free(households(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you free all your agents that have parameter=true and are in a wait block.... Hopefully it is what you want. Your algorithm is a bit messy.

```
    List <Agent> trueAgents=findAll(agents,a->a.parameter && a.currentBlock() instanceof Wait);

    for(Agent a : trueAgents){
        ((Wait)a.currentBlock()).free(a);
    }
```

And this can be simplified even further making an event when the parameter changes to true to free the agent immediately from the wait block without needing all these loops... but that depends on how your model works so I won't go into those details.

Comment: This is really a clever solution. I now can free the agents from AnyWhere ;D. Thank you very much .